# Power BI DESKTOP licensing - is it really free to share pbix files?

Tags: license, powerbi

The Power BI Desktop app for Windows is free, which is great. However, the Microsoft site is loaded with talk of licensing to share/view Power BI content. Is that only for their hosted Power BI *SERVICE*?

I want to create reports in Power BI Desktop, and distribute these as .pbix files. Is there any reason I can't distribute these without paying a dime? I realize that Microsoft's goal is to get people into their hosted Power BI service, but using Power BI Desktop (free app) to distribute content for free seems to good too be true.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about licensing should be directed to the vendor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are absolutely free to build and distribute .pbix files by file shares or OneDrive, or SharePoint Online.  Eventually this will lead to Power BI Service usage, or at least your team mates will want brand new Surface PCs to run Power BI Desktop.

And in any case you are investing your precious time in learning the technology and spreading its use.

Comment: "lead to Power BI Service usage" meaning that Microsoft would hope to up-sell the customer to the service, or that Microsoft is planning on phasing out non-service usage?

Comment: The up-sell one.

Comment: Excellent. This is good news for the usage I am thinking of. The only thing I would really like to be able to do that I can't is open a .pbix file in the Power BI app on smartphones. Maybe someday my company will be willing to invest in the Power BI service.

Comment: Or your _next_ company.

Comment: Strange. I always thought that you would require a license to publish `*.pbix` files as in **A Publisher License**. Am I wrong? So that would mean either an Enterprise Edition license key ***or*** a Power BI Publisher license to allow you to publish content.

Comment: Power BI Pro licenses are required to publish to shared workspaces on PowerBI.com.  “Publishing” to a file share or OneDrive does not.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Is this also valid for **Power BI for Reporting Services**?

Comment: Power Bi Report Server is a server product.  Other than evaluation and developer installs, installing PBIRS requires a license.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create reports in Power BI Desktop, and distribute these as .pbix files. Is there any reason I can't distribute these without paying a dime? I realize that Microsoft's goal is to get people into their hosted Power BI service, but using Power BI Desktop (free app) to distribute content for free seems to good too be true.

The `.pbix` files can be distributed to people but users must also have same or higher version of Power BI desktop installed at their end to view or utilize `.pbix` files.

However, you might be interested in `SSRS Power BI Server` [which mined here - similar to your scenario](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/245657/power-bi-upload-to-sql-reporting-services-2016/245692#245692)..